# A polygon uses the same vertex twice error in animation nodes

Tags: animation-nodes

I am trying to recreate the animation nodes example from the online documentation that is here.
https://animation-nodes-manual.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/nodes/mesh/operators/create_polygon_indices.html

I get an error at the combine mesh node (Which used to be the Combine Mesh Data Node) "A polygon uses the same Vertex twice"

I have tried fix it but couldn't. I would like to know why. Thanks. I am using animation nodes 2.1.7
and Blender 2.83.1

I have attached the Blend file.

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=pNk29ld9" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/pNk29ld9/)

Comment: `(number + 1) % number` will always return 1, so you output the same integer twice to the vertices list on your first iteration. You also output the same number with 0 added to the third input of your vertices. What were you trying to achieve ?

Comment: I was trying to get the example animation working that I copied from the first link

Comment: Oh okay, I didn't see you were copying the docs. Glad you figured it out !

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by connecting the math add node to index instead of iterations and added the edges of polygons node.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the documentation it shows earlier version of animation nodes which didn’t require you to add the edges to create a mesh. In v2.1, if you want to remove any errors make sure you add the vertices then edge indices then polygon. I don’t think you need a maths node, you just need to connect your edge indices from the original mesh info straight to your Combine Mesh Node and everything should work.

Comment: If you don’t have an edge indices, try creating one from the vertices you have.